# Fetching DataKeyValue of selected row (upon radiobutton checked) of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am new to Telerik controls. I have a RadGrid on my web page with RadiobButton next to each row inside RadGrid. I want to fetch the Datakeyvalue (primary key) of the selected row when particula row's RadioButton is checked.

I tried below code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None">
   <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
   <MasterTableView DataKeyName="Id">
       <ColumnGroups>
         <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="" HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:RadioButton ID="rbdSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"     OnCheckedChanged="rbdSelect_CheckedChanged"></asp:RadioButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
       </ColumnGroups>
```

```
protected void rbdSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.Items)
    {
        RadioButton rbd = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rbdSelect");
        if (rbd.Checked==true)
        {
            string key = item.GetDataKeyValue("Id").ToString();
            //string id = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items[0].GetDataKeyValue("Id").ToString();
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/PrintInvoice.aspx");
}
```

But its not working. Please help me how to retrieve the selected row Id/DataKeyValue.

Also, I want to pass the Id/DataKeyvalue of selected row of RadGrid on other page say "Default2.aspx"
Please somebody help me how to achieve it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: Everytime "string key" returns null/empty.

I tried to fetch the value inside "Label" control, then too it gives empty/null result.

Please reply what mistake I am making

Comment: I am getting "null" inside "string key" (where I am fetching datakeyvalue)
Please somebody reply what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Got the solution. Since RadGrid is bind through WebService (at client side using Javascript) and I was trying to fetch datakeyvalue at server side therefore everytime datakeyvalue was showing null.
Tried to fetch datakeyvalue using Javascript and the code is working fine. Thankyou

Comment: Great that you solved your own answer. It would be helpful to readers in the future if you could [answer your own question by using the button/field below](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (don't edit your answer into your post above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Since RadGrid is bind through WebService (at client side using Javascript) and I was trying to fetch datakeyvalue at server side therefore everytime datakeyvalue was showing null. Tried to fetch datakeyvalue using Javascript and the code is working fine. Thankyou –